# R - Is there at least one match between comma separated lists?

Tags: r

Here is the data I'm currently working with:

```
    structure(list(PortfolioID = c("z036527321", "z036527321", "z036527321", 
"z036526431", "z036526421", "z036526421", "z036526301", "z036525571", 
"z036525571", "z036525571", "z036525391", "z036525391", "z036525391", 
"z036525391", "z036525391", "z036525391", "z036525391", "z036525341", 
"z036525341", "z036524141", "z036524061", "z036523701", "z036523701", 
"z036523701", "z036523701", "z036523701", "z036523701", "z036523701", 
"z036523701", "z036523701", "z036522711", "z036521591", "z036521591", 
"z036521541", "z036521541", "z036521431", "z036521431", "z036521431", 
"z036521431", "z036521431", "z036521431", "z036521431", "z036521431", 
"z036521431", "z036521431", "z036520791", "z036520791", "z036520791", 
"z036520791", "z036520671", "z036520671", "z036520671", "z036520671", 
"z036520671", "z036520051", "z036520041", "z036519831", "z036519831", 
"z036519831", "z036519831", "z036519221", "z036519191", "z036518281", 
"z036518281", "z036517381", "z036516621", "z036516571", "z036516571", 
"z036516571", "z036516571", "z036516571", "z036516571", "z036516571", 
"z036516571", "z036516541", "z036516541", "z036516541", "z036515311", 
"z036515311", "z036515311", "z036515311", "z036515301", "z036515301", 
"z036515301", "z036515301", "z036515301", "z036515301", "z036515301", 
"z036515301", "z036515301", "z036515301", "z036515301", "z036515301", 
"z036515301", "z036515301", "z036515301", "z036515301", "z036515301", 
"z036515301", "z036515301"), `Enterprise Customer Party ID` = c("100600263, 100782628, 100753805, 100770731, 101360754, 103126734", 
"100600263, 100782628, 100753805, 100770731, 101360754, 103126734", 
"100600263, 100782628, 100753805, 100770731, 101360754, 103126734", 
"100175650, 100434367, 100600263, 103507556, 101519578, 103134259, 103134510", 
"100022778, 100570834, 100600263, 103514678, 101514778", "100022778, 100570834, 100600263, 103514678, 101514778", 
"100189878, 100600263, 101199515, 100746736", "101065177, 103502728, 101392726, 101404531", 
"101065177, 103502728, 101392726, 101404531", "101491312, 101404531, 103493687", 
"100363017, 100379794, 100600263, 100616003, 101296443, 103133788", 
"100363017, 100379794, 100600263, 100616003, 101296443", "100363017, 100379794, 100600263, 100616003, 101296443, 103130494", 
"100363017, 100379794, 100600263, 100616003, 101296443, 103130494", 
"100363017, 100379794, 100600263, 100616003, 101296443, 103130494", 
"100379794, 100363017, 100600263, 100616003, 101296443", "100379794, 100363017, 100600263, 100616003, 101296443, 103130494", 
"100175650, 100219612, 100434367, 100600263, 103510210, 103124599", 
"100175650, 100219612, 100600263, 103510210, 103124599, 103124680", 
"100189878, 100386081, 100556993, 100951842, 103521916", "100255427, 100599889, 100600263, 100787593, 101318358, 101466804", 
"100541378, 100600263, 100917340, 100991230", "100600263, 100640734, 100917340, 100991230, 103135413, 103489659", 
"100600263, 100640734, 100917340, 100991230, 103489659", "100600263, 100640734, 100917340, 100991230, 103489659", 
"100541378, 100600263, 100917340, 100991230", "100600263, 100640734, 100917340, 100991230, 103135413, 103489659", 
"100541378, 100600263, 100917340, 100991230", "100600263, 100640734, 100917340, 100991230, 103489659", 
"100600263, 100640734, 100917340, 100991230, 103489659", "100600263, 100987563, 101475026, 101513471, 101558213", 
"100180069, 100600263, 100714430, 101380893", "100180069, 100600263, 100693475, 100714430, 101380893", 
"100600263, 100647941, 100714430, 101497006, 101380893, 103663428", 
"100600263, 100693475, 100714430, 101497006, 101380893", "100513394, 100600263, 101250322, 100888261, 101484512", 
"100513394, 100600263, 101250322, 101488513", "100513394, 100600263, 100680615, 101250322", 
"100513394, 100600263, 100748241, 101250322", "100259186, 100513394, 100600263, 100647941, 101250322", 
"100325289, 100513394, 100600263, 101250322", "100513394, 100600263, 101250322, 101270920", 
"100358051, 100513394, 100600263, 101250322", "100513394, 100600263, 100845917, 101250322", 
"100513394, 100566608, 100600263, 101250322", "100154267, 100219612, 100600263, 101213228, 103498394, 103147666", 
"100154267, 100219612, 100600263, 101213228, 103498394, 103147666", 
"100154267, 100219612, 100600263, 101213228, 103498394, 103147666", 
"100154267, 100219612, 100600263, 101213228, 103498394, 103147666", 
"100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 100856914", "100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 100856914", 
"100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 100856914", "100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 100856914", 
"100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 100856914", "100482176, 100600263, 100615160, 100784263, 101374469", 
"100600263, 101360754, 103124701, 101436015", "100600263, 100655349, 100684621, 100823164, 101254987, 100770731, 100896421", 
"100600263, 100655349, 100684621, 100823164, 101254987, 100896421", 
"100600263, 100655349, 100684621, 100823164, 101254987, 100770731, 100896421", 
"100600263, 100684621, 100655349, 100823164, 101254987, 100770731, 100896421", 
"100513394, 100569469, 100600263, 100693475, 101344508", "100513394, 100600263, 101250322, 103124606, 103143455", 
"100178006, 103513498, 101404531", "100178006, 103513498, 101404531", 
"100532433, 100600263, 100685774, 100787593, 101344508, 103524479", 
"100110952, 100600263, 100879526, 103147348, 103147682, 103147890", 
"100086400, 100600263, 100991230, 103524505, 103125230, 103135888", 
"100086400, 100600263, 100991230, 103524505, 103125230, 103135888", 
"100086400, 100600263, 100991230, 103524505, 103125230, 103135888", 
"100086400, 100600263, 100991230, 103524505, 103125230, 103135888", 
"100086400, 100600263, 100991230, 103524505, 103125230, 103135888", 
"100086400, 100600263, 100991230, 103524505, 103125230, 103135888", 
"100086400, 100600263, 100991230, 103524505, 103125230, 103135888", 
"100086400, 100600263, 100991230, 103524505, 103125230, 103135888", 
"100566667, 100600263, 100603186, 103130050", "100566667, 100600263, 100603186, 103531703, 103128007", 
"100566667, 100600263, 100603186, 103531703, 103128007", "100505868, 100600263, 100879526, 101436015, 103139491, 103482495", 
"100505868, 100600263, 100879526, 103139491, 101436015, 103482495", 
"100505868, 100600263, 100879526, 101436015, 103139491, 103482495", 
"100505868, 100600263, 100879526, 101436015, 103139491, 103482495", 
"100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 103145053", "100386081, 100600263, 101050657, 100746736", 
"100386081, 100600263, 101050657, 100746736", "100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 101050657", 
"100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 103145053", "100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 101381649", 
"100386081, 100600263, 101050657, 100746736", "100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 103145053", 
"100386081, 100600263, 101050657, 100746736", "100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 103145053", 
"100019889, 100386081, 100587086, 100600263, 100746736, 103516226, 103629951, 101540702, 103143165", 
"100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 101381649", "100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 101381649", 
"100386081, 100587086, 100600263, 100746736, 101540702, 103147108", 
"100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 101381649", "100019889, 100386081, 100587086, 100600263, 100746736, 103516226, 103629951, 101540702, 103143165", 
"100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 101381649", "100019889, 100386081, 100587086, 100600263, 100746736, 103516226, 101540702, 103629951, 103143165", 
"100189878, 100386081, 100951842, 101381649")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am needing to know if there is a way to find out if there is at least one matching value in column B amongst all of the same portfolioID's. For example, for PortfolioID z036527321 we can see that there definitely is one match among the lists (100600263, and plenty of others). There will be some PortfolioID's where there isn't one match between them all. All I'm needing is an indicator of some sort. Put a 1 if all portfolios have one matching value and 0 if not. I really appreciate the help ahead of time. Thank you!

Comment: If there is only one portfolio, should it be `TRUE` or `FALSE` then?

Comment: Hey @Martin Gal, I would ideally like it to just be TRUE since it has nothing to match against. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  add_count(PortfolioID) %>%
  mutate(`Enterprise Customer Party ID` = str_split(`Enterprise Customer Party ID`, ", ")) %>% 
  unnest(`Enterprise Customer Party ID`) %>% 
  group_by(PortfolioID) %>%
  add_count(`Enterprise Customer Party ID`) %>% 
  summarise(match = any(n == nn)) %>% 
  right_join(data, by = "PortfolioID")
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 100 x 3
   PortfolioID match `Enterprise Customer Party ID`            
   <chr>       <lgl> <chr>                                     
 1 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 103145053
 2 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 101050657, 100746736
 3 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 101050657, 100746736
 4 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 101050657
 5 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 103145053
 6 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 101381649
 7 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 101050657, 100746736
 8 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 103145053
 9 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 101050657, 100746736
10 z036515301  TRUE  100386081, 100600263, 100746736, 103145053
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Comment: This worked perfectly and quickly, thank you so much @Martin Gal

Answer (score 4):

After grouping by 'PortfolioID', split the `Enterprise Customer Party ID` column, get the `intersect` of the `list` elements with `reduce`, check its `length` and convert to logical with `is_greater_than`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(PortfolioID) %>% 
    mutate(new = reduce(strsplit(`Enterprise Customer Party ID`, 
           ",\\s+"), intersect) %>%
        length %>%
        is_greater_than(0)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 100 x 3
   PortfolioID `Enterprise Customer Party ID`                                              new  
   <chr>       <chr>                                                                       <lgl>
 1 z036527321  100600263, 100782628, 100753805, 100770731, 101360754, 103126734            TRUE 
 2 z036527321  100600263, 100782628, 100753805, 100770731, 101360754, 103126734            TRUE 
 3 z036527321  100600263, 100782628, 100753805, 100770731, 101360754, 103126734            TRUE 
 4 z036526431  100175650, 100434367, 100600263, 103507556, 101519578, 103134259, 103134510 TRUE 
 5 z036526421  100022778, 100570834, 100600263, 103514678, 101514778                       TRUE 
 6 z036526421  100022778, 100570834, 100600263, 103514678, 101514778                       TRUE 
 7 z036526301  100189878, 100600263, 101199515, 100746736                                  TRUE 
 8 z036525571  101065177, 103502728, 101392726, 101404531                                  TRUE 
 9 z036525571  101065177, 103502728, 101392726, 101404531                                  TRUE 
10 z036525571  101491312, 101404531, 103493687                                             TRUE 
# … with 90 more rows
```

Comment: This was great @akrun, thank you so much for all of your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

I copied the data you provided into a data frame called `foo`.

In this solution a new column is created (called 'any_match') that shows `TRUE` if there are duplicate Enterprise Customer Party IDs for the same PortfolioID. It returns a `FALSE` if there are no duplicates.

The only instances of `FALSE` that are showing up in this solution is when there is only 1 row for the PortfolioID. So obviously there will be no duplicates because only 1 instance of the PortfolioID exists.

```
library(tidyverse)

foo %>%
  split(foo$PortfolioID) %>%
  map_dfr(function(pID) {
    
    pID_ecpid <- str_split(pID$`Enterprise Customer Party ID`, ', ') 
    
    match_check <- rep(NA, length(pID_ecpid))
    
    for (i in 1:length(pID_ecpid)) {
      check_with <- pID_ecpid[[i]]
      check_against <- unlist(pID_ecpid[-i])
      match_check[i] <- any(check_with %in% check_against)
    }
    
    pID <- pID %>%
      mutate(any_match = all(match_check))
    
    return(pID)
    
  })
```

Comment: This is really close to what I'm needing, thank you so much for your help. I'm really needing this to check and make sure that every instance of the portfolioID has one that matches. I think your code is looking to see if there's at least 1 duplicate for a given portfolioID. For instance if a PortfolioID has 5 rows, I need to know if all 5 rows have at least one that matches. If not all 5 have one that match then FALSE and if they all do then TRUE. @Harrison Jones

Comment: Made some edits. Try this version and see if it fixes the issue. Do you have an example of a PortfolioID where this is happening? I can't find any.

Comment: This ended up working great, just took a long time to finish. @Harrison Jones, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Base R

```
# Function to split the strings into a vector:
# strsplit_to_vec => function() 
strsplit_to_vec <- function(vec, pattern){
  return(unlist(strsplit(vec, pattern)))
}

# Apply the function on each element of the 
# multi-valued attribute Enterprise Customer Party ID
# grouped by PortfolioId: 
# split_str_list => list of character vectors
split_str_list <- lapply(
  split(
    df$`Enterprise Customer Party ID`,
    df$PortfolioID
  ), 
  strsplit_to_vec, 
  ",\\s+"
)

# Determine if any other portfolio contains thos ecpids:
# matching_ecpid => numeric vector
matching_ecpid <- setNames(
  vapply(
    seq_along(split_str_list),
    function(i){
      tmp_vec <- do.call(c, split_str_list[-i])
      if(length(intersect(split_str_list[[i]], tmp_vec)) > 0){
        1
      }else{
        0
      }
    }, 
    numeric(1)
  ),
  names(split_str_list)
)

# Assign the result back to the data.frame: 
# ecpid_match => numeric vector
df$ecpid_match <- matching_ecpid[
  match(
    df$PortfolioID,
    names(matching_ecpid)
  )
]
```